# What does it mean for iOS FileManager to be thread-safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, nsfilemanager

I'm reading/writing files and folders in a multithreaded iOS app.
I want these operations to be thread-safe.

NSFileManager's documentation says that "you should create a unique instance of the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations."

Such types of functions are used ( **the classification is mine** ):

**"Writing" operations**:

- NSData writeToFile: options:NSDataWritingAtomic
- NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath
- NSFileManager createFileAtPath
- NSFileManager removeItemAtPath

**"Reading" operations**:

- NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath
- NSFileManager subpathsAtPath

I'm choosing between such options for ensuring thread safety:

> 1. Create two NSFileManagers: one for "Writing" operations, one for "Reading" operations.  I call only atomic write, so NSFileManager
>      should protect the data consistency by itself.
> 2. Add a mutex, which will allow simultaneous reading/reading, but not simultaneous reading/writing or writing/writing.

**Could you advice which option is more correct/adequate?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the same Apple document:
"The methods of the shared FileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely."
If you are using the 'shared FileManager object' (and not an instance), you have thread-safety built-in.